# How to get value of Textboxes in Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

My program creating textboxes in panel1. I can give them a values on runtime. But i can't take values from textboxes left to the right.[textboxes look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZd7D.png) and i want to take values like 5, 215, 409, 607. My english so bad sorry about this. Please can someone help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Text`-values quite easily with LINQ, even without using the names of the textboxes.
Here is an example:

```
// creating a quick test-form with a panel:
var frm = new Form();
var pnl = new Panel() {Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
frm.Controls.Add(pnl);
for(int i = 1; i<10; i++)
{
    var tb = new TextBox() {Location = new Point(i*100, 15), Text = i.ToString(), Width = 80};
    pnl.Controls.Add(tb);
}

// get Texts from left to right
var textList = pnl.Controls.
    OfType<TextBox>().
    OrderBy(tb => tb.Left).
    Select(tb=> tb.Text).
    ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried Text property on the textbox object.  let say if your Textbox is TextBox1 then you need to use to read value from the text box "TextBox1.Text"?

You can visit [MSDN Help for textbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=net-5.0) if you need to learn more